Text Line contains invalid character ^^@
When building a latex document and miktex, I have a problem with corrupted aux files.
The error I get is
Text line contains an invalid character. [\newacro{SE^^@] which then extends to
Text line contains an invalid character. [\newacro{SE^^@^^@]
Text line contains an invalid character. [\newacro{SE^^@^^@^^@]  and repeats several times. In the aux, it's the zero character �
It seems to be due to acronyms used with the acronym package, but whenever I remove the seemingly corrupted acronym another error occurs.
After deleting the aux file, I have one or two compilations until the error shows up again. I tried converting all files to utf-8 to ensure that there were no weird characters, but that didn't help.
It also does not matter wether I use pdflatex or xelatex. Have any of you seen this error?
The error seems to be the same as in this question: Text line contains an invalid character. ...^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@...... vimtex
It'd be great to get a tip on what to try to fix that problem.

I would think it more likely you have a bad character in your tex file that's getting written to the aux.  Have you tried trimming down your tex file to a MWE that's causing the bad character to appear?

Welcome. // To second, my keyboard sometimes „creatively“ inserts what looks like Unicode characters, resulting in similar complaints.

^^@ is ascii NULL ie ascii.unicode character 0. as it is the aux  You will probably need to delete that file.  When you get a tex error take care to finish cleanly with x do not simply kill the terminal window. if you kill the process while it is writing files then you can end up with corruption like this
